# how to get xmm0 register raw data with gdb?

Tags: gdb

I use gdb to inject random bitnflips into code. I choose an operand of an instruction, read the value, change one bit and write it back. This works well, except for the xmm registers.

If I write:

```
-data-evaluate-expression $xmm0
^done,value="{v4_float = {0, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {0, 0}, v16_int8 = {0 <repeats 16 times>}, v8_int16 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, v4_int32 = {0, 0, 0, 0}, v2_int64 = {0, 0}, uint128 = 0}"
```

I get the possible interpretations of the register, but I need the raw data (in this case I think it would be `0x00000000` )

Additionally, I don't know how to set the xmm register with raw data, as this doesn't work

```
-gdb-set $xmm0=0x5d080000
^error,msg="Invalid cast."
```

Is there a way to acquire and set the raw data or do I have to find a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
-data-evaluate-expression $xmm0.uint128
-gdb-set $xmm0.uint128=0x5d080000
```